# Inner join the value of two combined columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need an inner join on two combined columns.

```
SELECT 
    [FullName], [Email], [Phone], [Goal], [TimeOfLead], [Location], [IPAddress] 
FROM 
    [Leads] 
INNER JOIN
    Clinics on [Clinics.City] + ', ' + [Clinics.State] as Location = Leads.Location 
WHERE
    Leads.Location = Clinics.Location
```

The `Leads` `Location` will always be the same as a `city` and `state` in the `clinics` table.

If I didn't explain this well enough, please let me know and I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. You don't need the `WHERE` clause again, since you are making the connection in the `INNER JOIN` itself.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    L.[FullName], L.[Email], L.[Phone], L.[Goal], L.[TimeOfLead], L.[Location], L.[IPAddress] 
FROM 
    [Leads] L
INNER JOIN
    Clinics C on L.Location = C.City + ', ' + C.State
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle with some sample data and the working query. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f53eb/2

**CREATE TABLES, POPULATE SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE Leads
( 
  FullName NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  Phone NVARCHAR(20) NULL, 
  Goal NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
  TimeOfLead NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  Location NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  IPAddress NVARCHAR(50) NULL  
);

CREATE TABLE Clinics
(
  ClinicName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  City NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  State NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Leads (FullName, Email, Location) VALUES
('John Duh', 'john@duh.com', 'San Francisco, CA'),
('Jane Dough', 'jane@dough.com', 'Austin, TX'),
('Bill Clinton', 'billy@presidents.com', 'Hope, AK');

INSERT INTO Clinics VALUES
('San Fran Clinic','San Francisco','CA'),
('Austin Clinic','Austin','TX'),
('Boise Clinic','Boise','ID'),
('Hope Clinic','Hope','AK');
```

EXECUTE QUERY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    L.[FullName], L.[Email], L.[Phone], L.[Goal], L.[TimeOfLead], L.[Location], L.[IPAddress] 
FROM 
    [Leads] L
INNER JOIN
    Clinics C on L.Location = C.City + ', ' + C.State
```

**RESULTS**

```
FULLNAME    EMAIL   PHONE   GOAL    TIMEOFLEAD  LOCATION    IPADDRESS
John Duh    john@duh.com    (null)  (null)  (null)  San Francisco, CA   (null)
Jane Dough  jane@dough.com  (null)  (null)  (null)  Austin, TX  (null)
Bill Clinton    billy@presidents.com    (null)  (null)  (null)  Hope, AK    (null)
```

Comment: That's probably because there are more than one record for each Lead or Clinic.  Use a "SELECT DISTINCT" to get unique records.

Comment: @Jim is right. Updated query and sample code to use `DISTINCT`.